# Android: how to make dependency between input and items quantity in Menu?

Tags: java, android

In my app I have Settings dialogue and Menue with items. User inputs a number in Settings dialogue and the quantity of items in Menue should depend on this number. How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No code, can't answer...sorry.

Comment: share what you have done so far.. put some code .. that would help other help you in a much better way